# ExpressJS compression and caching not working together

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, caching

ExpressJS [compression](https://www.npmjs.com/package/compression) module and [caching](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apicache) module are not working together in my project.

```
var compression = require('compression');
var express = require('express');
var apicache = require('apicache')
var cache = apicache.middleware

app.use(compression());
app.use(cache('5 minutes'))
```

I have this code in my server.js file which is serving an angular application.

Both modules are working individually as in if caching is disabled the response comes compressed and if compression is disabled, the server is caching the API results.
But when I add both of the modules to run together, it fails and APIs stop giving any response (basically API caching stop working though compression works fine in this case too).
Can you please help with what all could be the possible reasons for the same and how can I resolve them.

Comment: _"are not working together"_ in what way, exactly?

Comment: I have edited the question. pls let me know if anything else needs to be provided

Comment: I can reproduce the issue, it looks like a problem in `apicache` ([this issue](https://github.com/kwhitley/apicache/issues/120) also suggests that there are issues, although perhaps not exactly the same, when using `compression` in combination with `apicache`)